# create a new id, by groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert into my table a new `ID`, which makes it possible to cluster lines into one group. My data contain authors who published together,  author 1 (`auid1`) published with author 2 (`auid2`). I would like to find out if there are groups of authors in my data who published together and build a network. So every `group_id` will mark one network.

There is an additional condition: authors belong to the same group if every author published with everyone else in his group. That means, one auid can be in more than one group. 
Here is an example of my data:

```
auid_1      auid_2  
--------------------
001         002     
008         002     
010         007     
001         008     
007         005     
005         010     
008         003     
007         012     
004         005     
006         005     
004         006     
004         009
```

The result should look like this:

```
auid_1      auid_2      group_id     
---------------------------------
001         002         1 
008         002         1 
010         007         2 
001         008         1 
007         005         2 
005         010         2 
008         003         3 
007         012         4 
004         005         5 
006         005         5 
004         006         5 
004         009         6
```

Additional information: 
I use Qracle 11g, enterprise edition
We have pairs of IDs, examples:

```
ID1  ID2
--------
1    2    
3    2    
1    3
4    5
...
```

We want to allocate a group `ID` for all pairs which have a relationship to each other. In my example, `ID` 1 and 2 and 3 (every `ID` belongs to the other) are one cluster. The next cluster would be 4, 5, ....
We need a SQL query which do this clustering for us. I think, we need recursion? We don´t know the count of IDs per cluster.

Is it understandable now?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I use Qracle 11g, enterprise edition

Comment: This is more of a mathematical problem than a programming one.  How would you do this "manually", without SQL?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to find all the distinct graphs that can be built using given edges - is that so? This isn't really a job for SQL - can't you do this in a separate application / script? On the surface, recursion does seem to be the most straight-forward solution, but perhaps you could do the same with some clever use of ordering and windowing functions.

Comment: We have millions of data and hope we can do it directly on the database without exporting the data.